# Span a textarea across two columns in CSS Grid

Tags: textarea, css-grid

I have created a Grid in order to style a contact form into two two columns. I had a lot of trouble getting flexbox to play nicely with the labels and inputs, but I'm not opposed to using it if someone has a nice solution.

For my Grid, I have placed each pair of label/inputs in a div named contact-form__item. Everything is working well except for the textarea, named contact-form__comments, which will not span across the grid's columns. I have the textarea width set to 100% as has been recommended in other posts.The textarea declaration is in the media query at the very bottom of the enclosed styles.

I'm not opposed to using tables, but I have not pursued this solution yet. I would like to keep it simple with Grid, but I can't find a solution.

I have clipped my html:

```
<!-- CONTACT US -->
    <section class="contact">
        <h2 class="contact-heading heading-primary">Contact Us</h2>
        <form action="#" method="post" class="contact-form">

            <div class="contact-form__item">
                <label for="first-name">First name</label>
                <input id="first-name" type="text" class="contact-form__input">
            </div>
           
            <div class="contact-form__item">
                <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                <input id="last-name" type="text" class="contact-form__input">
            </div>
            
            <div class="contact-form__item">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" class="contact-form__input">
            </div>
            
            <div class="contact-form__item">
                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="phone" type="phone" class="contact-form__input">
            </div>
           
            <div class="contact-form__item">
                <label for="age">Age</label>
                <input id="age" type="text" class="contact-form__input">
            </div>

            <div class="contact-form__item">
                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                <select class="contact-form__select" id="gender" name="gender">
                    <option value="" selected></option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                    <option value="non-binary">Non-Binary</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-form__item">
                <label for="comments">Comments</label>
                <textarea class="contact-form__comments" name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="10">Tell us more...</textarea>
            </div>
            
            <input class="contact-form__input__submit" type="submit" value="Submit Here">
        </form>
    </section>
```

And my styles:

```
&-form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 60%;
        margin: auto auto;
        gap: 1rem;

        @media only screen and (min-width: $bp-tabport) {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            gap: 1rem 3rem;
        }

        &__input {
            background-color: $color-purple;
            color: $color-yellow;
            border: none;
            height: 3rem;
            padding: 1rem;
            border-radius: 5px;

           

            &__submit {
                justify-self: center;
                background-color: $color-yellow;
                color: $color-purple;
                font-size: 2rem;
                font-weight: 600;
                border: none;
                padding: .6rem;
                border-radius: 5px;;
                width: 60%;
                margin: auto auto;
                margin-top: 2rem;
                grid-column: 1 / -1;
            }
        }

        &__item {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        &__select {
            color: $color-yellow;
            padding: .6rem;
            background-color: $color-purple;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        &__comments {
            color: $color-yellow;
            padding: .6rem;
            background-color: $color-purple;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 100%;

            @media only screen and (min-width: $bp-tabland) {
                grid-column: 1 / 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried using flexbox with no success. So, I switched to Grid. I have set textarea width to 100%. I have also tried increasing the cols in the html. Have not tried tables.

Comment: Edit your question to add a snippet, which allows us to run your code and see what it does. We can also then copy your snippet to our answer, making the necessary adjustments to get it working for you.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. But what is a snippet and how do I include one? Thanks.

Comment: A snippet is Stack Overflow's equivalent of a Codepen or a jsFiddle. When you're adding or editing a question, look at the tools at the top of the editor. Just to the right of the *image* tool is the *snippet* tool. When you use that tool it will open the snippet editing window, so just add some HTML, CSS and Javascript code, and run them to see the result. If you can get your snippet to reproduce the problem, then we'll have that problem sorted for you pronto. It doesn't support SASS though, so you'll have to use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

You set a `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` on your form, by default your `textarea` container will only take up one column of space. So, you need to add this to your textarea container div:

```css
contact-form__item:last-of-type {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

A better way is to add a modifier:

```css
contact-form__item--full {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

or

```css
contact-form__item--full {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```